# Errors using UNION in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I tried to understand how UNION works in SQL Server by executing the following script:

```
select * 
from Production.ProductModel
where ProductModelID IN (3,4, 5, 6)
UNION
select * 
from Production.ProductModel
where ProductModelID NOT IN (3,4, 5, 6)
```

Got following error:

> The data type xml cannot be used as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable.

It seems few other people got similar and posted in stack overflow; but, unfortunately I didn't understand the explanation by some champs. Can any please help me to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Union in SQL while creating XML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37430288/union-in-sql-while-creating-xml-file)

Comment: Switch to use UNION ALL and it won't check for duplicates. Then your query should work without error.

Answer (score 4):

In SQL Server values of some data types cannot be compared to each other. `xml` is one of that types. Try

```
SELECT 1
       WHERE convert(xml, '<r/>') = convert(xml, '<r/>');
```

and you'll get

> The XML data type cannot be compared or sorted, except when using the IS NULL operator.

`UNION` does eliminate duplicates in the end result of the operation and therefore must compare the rows and ultimately the values in the columns for equality.

Now you apparently have an `xml` column in `productmodel` and the `UNION` triggers such a comparison. That comparison however fails, because, as mentioned, `xml`s cannot be compared.

That's why you see

> The data type xml cannot be used as an operand to the UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operators because it is not comparable.

You can use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` however, as this doesn't eliminate duplicates and therefore doesn't need to compare the `xml`s.

Comment: This is a well-written answer, but I would take it to the next step and ask if they need the xml column in the result set.  Because, as you've implied, they can either eliminate the duplicate rows OR remove the column (but not both) using this method.

Comment: Thank you Champ for your explanation... also grateful for all the champs towards contributing their valuable time to 'stack overflow'

Answer (score 2):

When using UNION or UNION ALL, I always specify the column names.

1. UNION: Sorts and removes duplicate rows
2. UNION ALL: Does not sort and does not remove duplicate rows.